# Python: startswith any alpha character

Tags: python, startswith

How can I use the startswith function to match any alpha character [a-zA-Z].  For example I would like to do this:

```
if line.startswith(ALPHA):
    Do Something
```

Answer (score 62, accepted):

If you want to match non-ASCII letters as well, you can use [`str.isalpha`](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalpha):

```
if line and line[0].isalpha():
```

Comment: Even shorter: `if line[:1].isalpha():`

Comment: @Will What is the difference between your answer and `if line[0].isalpha():`

Comment: @teggy: The difference is that if line is an empty string, line[:1] will evaluate to an empty string while line[0] will raise an IndexError.

Answer (score 13):

You can pass a tuple to `startswiths()` (in Python 2.5+) to match any of its elements:

```
import string
ALPHA = string.ascii_letters
if line.startswith(tuple(ALPHA)):
    pass
```

Of course, for this simple case, a regex test or the `in` operator would be more readable.

Comment: I did not know that. +1 not for the best answer for this question, but because that is by far the best answer for a ton of my own code. Thank you.

Answer (score 9):

An easy solution would be to use the python regex module:

```
import re
if re.match("^[a-zA-Z]+.*", line):
   Do Something
```

Comment: -1: Using regex is massively overkill for this task.  Also you only need to check the first character - this regex will try and match the whole string, which could be very long.

Comment: Even if you were forced to use the re module, all you needed was `[a-zA-Z]`. The `^` is a waste of a keystroke (read the docs section about the difference between `search` and `match`). The `+` is a minor waste of time (major if the string has many letters at the start); one letter is enough. The `.*` is a waste of 2 keystrokes and possibly a lot more time.

Answer (score 3):

This is probably the most efficient method:

```
if line != "" and line[0].isalpha():
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if line.startswith((chr(x) for x in range(ord('a'), ord('z')+1)+range(ord('A'), ord('Z')+1)):
    # do processsing
    pass
```

Answer (score -1):

if you don't care about blanks in front of the string,

```
if line and line.lstrip()[0].isalpha():
```